# Как узнать value выбранного option если name у селектов одинаковый

Tags: jquery

```
<select name="prepay">
    <option value="100"><span>100</span>%</option>
    <option value="30"><span>30</span>%</option>
    <option value="10"><span>10</span>%</option>
</select>
<select name="prepay">
    <option value="100"><span>100</span>%</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="10"><span>10</span>%</option>
    <option value="20"><span>20</span>%</option>
</select>
```

Comment: в данной разметке - ни один не выбран

Comment: это противоречит логике, даже если у вас имена одинаковые, желательно им id добавить и при этом разные.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, в чем противоречие? id - необязательный атрибут

Comment: А если я вывожу массив товара через foreach ,генерируя селекты, т.е. селектов неизвестное количество

Comment: Воспользуйтесь методом `on()` и `this`

Comment: задайте им номера относительно того, к чему они у вас в базе привязаны, например id с чем они связаны.

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, громадный кусок разметки в комментариях смотрится не очень, лучше добавьте в виде ответа

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('select[name="prepay"]').change(function(){
   var val = $(this).val();
       alert(val);
})
```

Comment: я не удивлюсь если можно сократить до `$(this).val();`

Comment: интересно, почему минус на ответе

Comment: возможно потому что, что зачем то навешано событие на селекты

Comment: @ДмитрийГвоздь, что значит зачем-то? чтобы в момент выбора значения - узнать на какое поменяли

Comment: да это понятно, но на подобную ситуацию ТС не указывал, он не указал при каких обстоятельствах надо получить данные.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то подобное писал уже @amijin, но я сторонник использовать `on()` для делегирования.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('change', 'select[name="prepay"]', function(){
        var percent = $(this).val();
        console.log(percent);
    });
});
```

Comment: повторюсь :-) _можно сократить до $(this).val();_

Comment: @Grundy Согласен, обновил

Answer (score 0):

А что например мешает использовать такой код?
Где все подписано.

```
<div class="select_block" id="idkey_42">
  <h5 class="radiohead">
    Оригинал 
  </h5>
  <select name="prm[42]" class="select" style="display: none;">
    <option selected="selected" value="0" id="" class="">
      - не важно -
    </option>
    <option value="3670" id="" class="">
      Audi
    </option>
  </select>
</div>
```